# Why get_tensor_by_name can't get the weights of layers defined by tf.keras.layers properly

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I try to get the weights of layers defined by `tf.keras.layers` by using `get_tensor_by_name` in `tensorflow`. The code is presented as follows

```
# encoding: utf-8
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None,3))
h = tf.keras.layers.dense(3)(x)
y = tf.keras.layers.dense(1)(h)

for tn in tf.trainable_variables():
    print(tn.name)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
w = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("dense/kernel:0")
print(sess.run(w))
```

The name of the weight is `dense/kernel:0`. However, the output of `sess.run(w)` is weird

```
[( 10,) ( 44,) ( 47,) (106,) (111,) ( 98,) ( 58,) (108,) (111,) ( 99,)
 ( 97,) (108,) (104,) (111,) (115,) (116,) ( 47,) (114,) (101,) 
 ... ]
```

which is not an array of floats. In fact, if I use `tf.layers.dense` to define the network, everything goes fine. So my question is that how I can get the weights of layers defined by `tf.keras.layers` by using tensor name properly.

Comment: Why do you need to use `get_tensor_by_name` ? You can get weight directly from layer

Comment: I know the way by using keras API. I just don't understand why `get_tensor_by_name` can't return the proper answer when using `keras` to define layers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_weights()` on layers to get the weight values of particular layers. Here is an example code for your case:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3], name='x')    
dense1 = tf.keras.Dense(3, activation='relu')
l1 = dense1(input_x)
dense2 = tf.keras.Dense(1)
y = dense2(l1)

weights = dense1.get_weights()
```

It can be done in a even simpler way with Keras API as follows:

```
def mymodel():
    i = Input(shape=(3, ))
    x = Dense(3, activation='relu')(i)
    o = Dense(1)(x)

    model = Model(input=i, output=o)
    return model


model = mymodel()

names = [weight.name for layer in model.layers for weight in layer.weights]
weights = model.get_weights()

for name, weight in zip(names, weights):
    print(name, weight.shape)
```

This example gets weight matrices for each layer of your model.

Comment: yes, I know the ways you suggested above. I just don't understand why `get_tensor_by_name` can't return the proper answer when using `keras` to define layers. In fact, I usually think that `tensorflow` is more easily to be used to define complex loss function than pure `keras`. Thus I just use `keras` to define the layers in model and using `tensorflow` elsewhere.

Comment: `I usually think that tensorflow is more easily to be used to define complex loss function than pure keras`...I do not totally agree but that's me. I think in Keras if you are accessing `dense/kernel:0`, it might refer to the output rather than the layer itself; probably the layer is called `Dense`.  Maybe you can check in TensorBoard how Keras is actually naming the tensors. I am just guessing here.

Comment: Also, Keras does not save the tensors as `dense/kernel:0`, rather `dense_1` if you print the `model.summary()`.

Comment: yes, I tried. In fact, no matter what the name of tensor is, the output is the same as presented above.

Comment: Probably Keras does not use the same names as in the TensorFlow computational graph