# Can we get weights by name in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

It is possible to get the layer object of a model `model` by doing `model.get_layer("layer_name")`.

**Is there any keras function to do something similar to the weights?**

The usage would be something like
`model.get_layer("layer_name").get_variable_by_name("recurrent_kernel")`

In a Layer built with the a recurrent weight defined as the following:

```
self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units, self.units),
        initializer=self.recurrent_initializer,
        name="recurrent_kernel", trainable=self.train_recurrent)
```

EDIT: This is not the solution I am looking for: [Why get_tensor_by_name can't get the weights of layers defined by tf.keras.layers properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56002345/why-get-tensor-by-name-cant-get-the-weights-of-layers-defined-by-tf-keras-layer)

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal, but while there's no answer. I am using this:

```
def get_weights_by_name(model, name):
    return [w for w in model.weights if w.name==name][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but then I figured out it was easy to get the weights by the variable itself. In your case, you could use `model.get_layer("layer_name").recurrent_kernel` to get the `tf.Variable`, and then call `.numpy()` to get the array of weights.

Comment: If users only want to access to that variable, it's fine to do it that way. However, if users want to use the layer class method to access weigts, e.g., `layer.get_weights()`, `layer.set_weights()` then it'd be ideal to be able to access different resource_variable by name, instead of integer index.